# 'Waiting' runs for Logic App not starting when the previous run was cancelled

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

The logic app has a queue to avoid concurrent runs. When I cancelled a run, the later runs in the queue do not start. Is there a way to force-start them?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to start the first queued run by triggering the LA manually. This of course adds another run to the queue (in my case with missing parameters as the logic app expected an HTTP body from the trigger), so it's not a perfect solution.